# What are peer to peer architectures

Tags: p2p

I am confusing about the classification of peer to peer architectures.
Are they structured and unstructured or the centralization levels(decentralized centralized and hybrid).
 
I searched a lot on the web but i didn't find any good results everyone says his opinion .
All what i need to know is what are those classifications .
Thanks for any suggestions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This wikipedia page (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Peer-to-peer) clearly describes 3 types of peer-to-peer architectures.

1. Unstructured
2. Structured
3. Hybrid

Are you sure you searched the web?

Answer (score 0):

There are three models of unstructured P2P computer network architecture:
1. Pure P2P
2. Hybrid P2P
3. Centralized P2P

In structured P2P computer network architecture, workstations (peers), and sometimes resources as well, are organized according to specific criteria and algorithms.